# Is there a specialized formula for Lagrangian interpolation on equispaced points?

Tags: polynomials, natural-numbers, lagrange-interpolation

If we know $f(0),f(1),f(2),\cdots f(n)$, is there a specialized version of the Lagrangian interpolation formula and a shortcut to compute the coefficients ?

(Stability is not a concern.)

Comment: See section 6.3.1 of E. Isaacson & H. B. Keller, *Analysis of Numerical Methods* (Wiley 1966, reprinted by Dover 1994), particularly formula (11) on page 265, which agrees with the accepted answer below.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley: thanks for this reference, also interesting in other respects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the $n+1$ points
$\{\left(x_0,f(x_0)\right),...,\left(x_n,f(x_n)\right)\}$
the Lagrange interpolating polynomial is defined as
$$P(x)=\sum_{j=0}^nP_j(x)=\sum_{j=0}^n f(x_j)\prod_{k=0\\{k\ne j}}^{n}\frac{x-x_k}{x_j-x_k}$$
Now since the $x_j=j,\; (j=0,1,...,n)$ the product can be simplified.

Let $p_n(x):=x(x-1)\cdots(x-n)$ then
$$\begin{align}\prod_{k=0\\{k\ne j}}^{n}\frac{x-x_k}{x_j-x_k}&=\prod_{k=0\\{k\ne j}}^{n}\frac{x-k}{j-k}
\\&=\frac{p_n(x)}{x-j}\prod_{k=0\\{k\ne j}}^{n}\frac 1{j-k}\\
&=\frac{p_n(x)}{x-j}\cdot\frac 1{j!(-1)^{n-j}(n-j)!}\\
&=\frac{p_n(x)}{n!}{{n}\choose{j}}\frac{(-1)^{n-j}}{x-j}
\end{align}$$
Therefore
$$P(x)=\frac{p_n(x)}{n!}\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^{n-j}{{n}\choose{j}}\frac{f(j)}{x-j}$$

Comment: The quantity you denote $p_n(x)$, a "falling factorial", is often denoted $(x)_{n + 1}$. Alternatively, you can regard it as a "rising factor" and denote it using the Pochhammer symbol $(x - n)^{(n + 1)}$.

Comment: (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials for more.)

Comment: So the "weights" of the $P_j$ polynomials are essentially the binomial coefficients.