# I have the sequence: $1, 4, 10, 16, 19, 16, 10, 4, 1$. What is the formula to get the $i^{th}$ term of the sequence for $i=1,2,\dots,9$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, multinomial-coefficients, multinomial-theorem

I've been trying to derive this formula for quite some time now with little progress.

I've seen concepts such as Pascal's pyramids and Pascal's simplices mentioned throughout my research; however, I doubt their significance to the formula.

The most promising outlet I've seen are the coefficients that come from the expansion of $(1 + x^2 + x^3 +\dots + x^{r - 1})^n$ [for various values of $r$ and all values of $n$].

I've seen somewhat similar questions posted on Math SE before, but I'm struggling to find an answer that provides an accurate formula as well as a general breakdown of how it was achieved.

If someone could help, that would be great!

Comment: Use Lagrange interpolation formula for [equispaced points](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3261015/305862)

Comment: As you are explaining your objective, a (byzantine ?) way to answer your question is that your values are the coefficients of polynomial $x+4x^2+10x^3+\cdots +x^9$. What do you expect more ? A simpler expression with less terms ?

Answer (score 3):

Searching this sequence on the OEIS gives [A027907](http://oeis.org/A027907) which are the [trinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinomial_triangle); these are the coefficients in the expansion of $(1 + x + x^2)^4$. They can be expressed in terms of [multinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) (which in this case can be thought of as [Pascal's pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_pyramid) if you want to think of them that way) by the multinomial theorem; doing this gives that the $i^{th}$ term is

$$\sum_{a+2b=i} \frac{4!}{a! b! (4-a-b)!}.$$

For example, the $i = 2$ term is $\frac{4!}{0! 1! 3!} + \frac{4!}{2! 0! 2!} = 4 + 6 = 10$.

(There is a slightly unfortunate collision of terminology here; the trinomial coefficients are not the $3$-variable special case of the multinomial coefficients. Unfortunately I don't know a better name for these numbers.)

Comment: To put it another way, $(1+x+x^2)^4$ is the factorization of $1+4x+10x^2+\cdots+x^8$.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan Thank you so much for your answer! This confirms a couple things that I've been looking at. With that being said, could you possibly expand on how you got to the "a + 2b = i" in the summation constraint?

Comment: @rizevenk11: it comes from asking when a term in the multinomial expansion multiplies out to $x^i$. The $a$ contribution is the number of $x$ factors that occur and the $b$ contribution is the number of $x^2$ factors that occur.